# How to limit search to first letter of title?

Tags: query-posts, filters, search, query

I was wondering if there was a way to make the search only look for the first letter in the posts title, basically let's say my search query is www.mysite.com/?s=q I'd like to get all posts that start with the letter "Q". Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is too late but I hope it is going to help someone in the future
You can add a filter to posts_where and add a regexp to limit it to the first letter. [Wordpress documentation for posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where)

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where' );

function posts_where( $where ) {

if( is_admin() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_GET['author_restrict_posts'] ) && !empty( $_GET['author_restrict_posts'] ) && intval( $_GET['author_restrict_posts'] ) != 0 ) {
        $author = intval( $_GET['author_restrict_posts'] );

        $where .= " AND ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id=$author )";
    }
}
return $where;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to clarify slightly? I'm not sure what is_admin is doing here (is this filtering only happening in the dashboard or when logged in as admin?) and I can't figure out where in the query you're specifying the 'first character' part of the search.