# how to get wp_query posts only first letter of alphabet A?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, wp-title

I want to get all the data by wp_query only the first letter of title specific alphabet 'A'.

My code will be like:

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
         'posts_per_page'=>10,                                                                           
         'post_type'=>'trade-name',
         'orderby'=> 'title',
         'starts_with' => 'A',
         'order'   => 'ASC',
'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
```

Comment: Please have a look on this **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/298913/143123**

Comment: wow it works thanks @pratik patel

Comment: Happy to help you :)