# Query custom post type and custom field by URL parameters

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, urls

I have a custom post type `staff`. and a custom field `alphabet` for posts in that post type. Each staff will be assigned to a letter either `A` or `B` ... `Z` based on the first letter of the staff's name.

On the directory page there will be navigation links `A`, `B`, ... `Z`. Is it possible to list all posts with in each letter via URL parameters?

Example click link `A` to list all staff with name begins with letter A (Adam, Andrew...):

```
http://example.com/?post_type=staff&meta_key=alphabet&meta_value=A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you can start by implementing the solution for [this question.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298888/wp-query-where-title-begins-with-a-specific-letter) That will allow you to filter posts by their first letter (no custom meta required):

> Assuming `starts_with` is the name of the argument we want to use, we
>   can filter `posts_where` to add a `WHERE` clause limiting results to
>   those that begin with the given value if `starts_with` has been set on
>   the query:
>
> ```
> function wpse_298888_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
>   global $wpdb;
>
>   $starts_with = $query->get( 'starts_with' );
>
>   if ( $starts_with ) {
>       $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$starts_with%'";
>   }
>
>   return $where;
> }
> add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_298888_posts_where', 10, 2 );
> ```
>
> With this filter added, we can query posts like this:
>
> ```
> $query = new WP_Query( array(
>   'starts_with' => 'M',
> ) );
> ```
>
> That will return all posts beginning with "M".

To support filtering the post type archive this way via the URL, you just need to register `starts_with` as a query var:

```
function wpse_346729_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'starts_with';

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_346729_query_vars' );
```

Doing this means that if the `starts_with` parameter is passed via the URL, it will be set on the main query, which will cause our `posts_where` filter to be applied to the current main query.

```
http://example.com/?post_type=staff&starts_with=A
```